# overloaded mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

A few times a day, our database server does not shut down the processes in the sleep state and does not respond by slowing down access to the server. Here are two problems:

1. server 32gb ram etc. Although it is a machine that is higher than the average, 100-150 is starting to not respond to the "SLEEP connection", what is the reason?
2. PHP is used in our software after the query is processed in the DB class destruct method mysqli_close do. But it stays open on mysql server.

Can you help me?

Pics:

Connections: [They all remain open until 30 seconds have expired (wait_timeout)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDdy1.jpg)

General status: [average status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GgLG.jpg)

Comment: maybe you should ask that question on https://serverfault.com

Comment: thank you for reply, i did created question there now :)